# Proof of The Planar Separator Theorem

Tags: graph-theory

I can't understand the proof of The Planar Separator Theorem

> Any n-vertex planar graph has a 2/3-separator containing at most $\sqrt{8n}$ vertices.

Proof of the theorem [10 Graph Separators](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6822/2011fa/papers/separators.pdf)

Let's go through the proof.

Let $G$ be an embedded planar graph with $n \geq 3$ vertices, and let $k = \sqrt{2n}$ Without loss of generality, we can assume that $G$ has no loops or parallel edges, and that every face is a triangle bounded by three distinct edges. For any simple cycle $C$ in G, let $In(C)$ and $Out(C)$ denote the vertices inside and outside $C$,r respectively. No vertex of $In(C)$ is adjacent to any vertex of $Out(C)$. Let $C$ be a simple cycle satisfying three conditions:

1. $C$ has at most $2k$ vertices.
2. $|Out(C)| < 2n/3$.
3. Subject to conditions 1 and 2, the difference |In(C)| and |Out(C)| is as small as possible.

Let D be the subgraph of G in the closed interior of C. For any two vertices $u$ and $v$ in $C$, let $c(u, v)$ denote their distance in $C$, and let $d(u, v)$ denote their distance in $d$.

> **Claim 1**. $d(u, v) = c(u, v)$ for all vertices $u$ and $v$ in $C$.

We clearly have $d(u, v) \leq c(u, v)$ for all $u$ and $v$, because $C$ is a subgraph of $D$. Suppose there are distinct vertices $u$ and $v$ such that $d(u, v) < c(u, v)$ choose such a pair so that $d(u, v)$ is minimized. Let be a shortest path from $u$ to $v$ in D. If  contained any other vertex $w$ in C, then $d(u, w) + d(w, v) = d(u, v) < c(u, v) \leq c(u, w) + c(w, v)$, so either $d(u, w) < c(u, w)$ or $d(w, v) < c(w, v)$ either possibility contradicts our choice of $u$ and $v$.

[image]

How this is possible, take a look a at the picture. It's obviously that path in $D$ is shorter than path in $C$. The part with additional vertex $w$ wasn't understood at all, at the end we get contradiction of choice of $u$ and $v$.

> **Claim 2**. $C$ has exactly $2k$ vertices.

I can't get it too, because the proof is based on Claim 1.

Please, can you shed light on the proof.

Thanks!

**Addendum**:

1. We have 3 conditions that $C$ should satisfy
2. For purposes of deriving a contradiction, we have assumption $|In(C)| \geq 2n/3$
3. We choice $w$ and $v$ such that $d(u,v)$ is minimized and show that either $d(u, w) < c(u, w)$ or $d(w, v) < c(w, v)$; either possibility contradicts our choice of $u$ and $v$. But this is completely fine with minimized $d(u,w)$, what is the contradiction?
4. It turns out that we can find a better separation $C^{+}$, which is satisfies (1.1) and (1.2)(with assumption that 2 is true, which is already mistaken), but don't satisfy (1.3), and conclusion that claim is true. But how come, what about the contradiction of our choice of $u$ and $v$?

Sorry, it's not complication in terms of mathematics, but it's really mixed up in terms of logic.

Comment: If $G$ has $n$ vertices, and Out(C) has $< 2n/3$, shouldn't In(C) have $\geq n/3$ vertices? (Instead of $2n/3$ as you wrote?) Also, in the first line after claim 1, you want $d \leq c$ instead of $d < c$, I expect.

Comment: You only quoted the first half of the proof for Claim 1 from the linked PDf file. Try reading on the next few sentences. The basic idea is that $C$ is assumed to satisfy three conditions (the third one, especially, is an optimisation condition). If Claim 1 were violated, then the author shows one can construct another $C^+$ that better optimises condition 3, which contradicts the assumption that $C$ is the optimiser.

Comment: @WillieWong: Thank you for the comment, now I understand everything mathematically, but I still have a problem with logic. Please take a look at addendum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't contradict your choice of $u,v$. The choice of $u,v$ is to make sure that the minimum path connecting $u,v$ does not intersect $C$, so that the path connected $u,v$ divides $D$ into two (and not more) regions.

The contradiction is derived from making the difference between the number of points in In(C) and Out(C) as small as possible in the **initial** description of the curve $C$.

**Edit**: Ah, you are worried about the bit where the author assumes for contradiction...

The point is this. You have conditions

1. $C$ has at most $2k$ vertices
2. $Out(C)$ has at most $2n/3 - 1$ vertices
3. Optimisation condition.

Once you've chosen such a $C$, if $In(C)$ also has at most $2n/3 -1$ vertices, then $C$ is a 2/3 planar separator with at most 2k vertices, as demanded by the theorem. So it suffices to show that it is impossible for $In(C)$ to have more than $2n/3$ vertices. To do so, the authors show that if $|In(C)| \geq 2n/3$ you will get a contradiction.

To build up the contradiction, the author shows that if $|In(C)| \geq 2n/3$ he can construct a $C'$ such that it satisfies 1 and 2, but better optimises 3 (which would contradict our original choice of $C$ being the optimiser). The construction of $C'$ goes basically by cutting $In(C)$ in half using a length minimizer between two points on $C$. (This is to use the fact that one of the two halves will have Interior at least $n/3$.) If the path minimizer cuts $C$ in more than two pieces, you cannot guarantee that any piece will have interior more than $2n/9$. So you need to make sure that the path minimizer only cuts $C$ in half. And so the path minimizer is required to not intersect $C$. The choice of $u,v$ and the subsequence mini proof by contradiction guarantees that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, according to choice of $u,v$ there is written in the paper **"either possibility contradicts our choice of u and v"**, looks like it's not true. I understand that the newest and more optimal C contradicts to initial condition 3. But conclusion was made with assumption that $|In(C)|\geq \frac{2n}{3}$ which is false, so conclusion also may be false, the things are a little mixed up there

Comment: that phrase refers to the two alternatives immediately prior to that phrase. Read the paper again. That entire sentence from which "either possibility... choice of u and v" is taken is a _proof by contradiction_ of the fact that **no other point on the path between u and v can lie on C**.